# Classification_report between two files

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, metrics

I'm trying to do a score between two files. The two have the same data but not the same label. Labels from train data are corrects and the labels from test data not necessarily... and I would like to know the accuracy, recall and f-score.

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support as score
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score, confusion_matrix, classification_report, accuracy_score, f1_score

df_train = pd.read_csv('train.csv', sep = ',')
df_test = pd.read_csv('teste.csv', sep = ',')

vec_train = TfidfVectorizer()
X_train = vec_train.fit_transform(df_train['text'])
y_train = df_train['label']

vec_test = TfidfVectorizer()
X_test = vec_test.fit_transform(df_train['text'])
y_test = df_test['label']

clf = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', multi_class = 'multinomial',solver ='newton-cg')

y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

print ("Accuracy on training set:")
print (clf.score(X_train, y_train))
print ("Accuracy on testing set:")
print (clf.score(X_test, y_test))
print ("Classification Report:")
print (metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

A stupid example of the data:

```
TRAIN
text,label
dogs are cool,animal
flowers are beautifil,plants
pen is mine,objet
beyonce is an artist,person

TEST
text,label
dogs are cool,objet
flowers are beautifil,plants
pen is mine,person
beyonce is an artist,animal
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "accuracy.py", line 30, in 
>       y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 324, in predict
>       scores = self.decision_function(X)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 298, in decision_function
>       "yet" % {'name': type(self).**name**})
>   sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: This LogisticRegression instance is not fitted yet

I just wanted to calculate the accuracy of the test

Comment: You did not fitted your model at all!!! First you should use `fit()` funtion. then use `predict`. And you can use `confusion_matrix` to count true or false prediciton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fitting a new `TfidfVectorizer` on test data. This will give wrong results. You should use the same object which you fitted on train data.

Do this:

```
vec_train = TfidfVectorizer()
X_train = vec_train.fit_transform(df_train['text'])

X_test = vec_train.transform(df_test['text'])
```

After that, as @MohammedKashif said, you need to first train your LogisticRegression model and then predict on test.

```
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

After that you can use the scoring code without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first train your classifier object using the `X_train` before using the predict function over `X_test`. Something like this

```
clf = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', multi_class = 'multinomial',solver ='newton-cg')

#Then train the classifier over training data
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

#Then use predict function to make predictions
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```